# Is there an utility to parse an URL without checked exception in java?

Tags: java, exception

I'd like to create an URL constant, like so

```
public static final URL REMOTE_URL = new URL("http://example.com/");
```

But I can't since the constructor throw a checked exception. Right now I use

```
public static final URL REMOTE_URL = createUrl("http://example.com/");

private static URL createUrl(String url) {
    try {
        return new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException error) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(error.getMessage(), error);
    }
}
```

But it feel like reinventing the wheel. I can't possibly be the only one who want to use a URL constant no? So I was wondering if there is third-party toolbox library (like guava or apache-commons, or something else, anything) or even better, something in standard Java that include this facilities? That would help me when we start a new project by reducing the size of our util package :) .

Comment: So, you know the exception  is there for a reason, and you know the reason, and how Java checked exceptions work, so are you expecting a miracle here? If you know the exception won't occur, don't catch it. The compiler doesn't know this and can't possibly know this.

Comment: I believe you can instruct compiler to ignore them using some annotation @

Comment: @d'alar'cop Nope. That only works for warnings.

Comment: Declare your method to throw the exception.  I can't imagine that this would affect much, given the very narrow usage described.

Comment: @JoeCoder And how would you handle the constant case?

Comment: Some people get their panties in a bunch over the oddest things ;)  Personally, I'm just grateful that Java *has* a notion of "checked" exceptions, and *enforces* it.  *Unlike* C++, for example...

Comment: Oh, I have nothing against checked exception, *when they indicate that something out of my control can go wrong*. But it annoy me when they prevent me from doing simple stuff, like creating a constant that can't ever possibly fail...

Comment: I think your little utility, with some commenting to explain why it eats the checked exception, is the way to go.  If you put it into a class called "URLS" it will even sound like a Guava class.  :-)

Comment: @vanza Yep, I know about that ^^. My question was more : is there something that already exists to do it? I hate repeating myself and reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy You have this the wrong way around. *unchecked* exceptions are for programmer error or using an API wrong. (I.e. `ClassCastException`, `ArrayStoreException`.) *checked* exceptions are for when the failure is due to external circumstances. Handing a well-formed constant string to the `URL()` constructor is a very special-case, and the compiler can at best figure out by dataflow analysis that the parameter value comes from a literal, not its format. So, the overwhelming general case is that URL strings are *unsafe* input and the API reflects this.

Comment: (Okay, technically you could argue that it's a programmer error to not validate input for correctness, but the approach taken here is "better ask for forgiveness than for permission", and fits the philosophy that lead to the checked/unchecked exception dichotomy to begin with. Whether you agree with that philosophy is another discussion, but it's consistent within this framework to make `MalformedURLException` checked.)

Comment: @millimoose that's a reasonable point of view, and in general I tend to tolerate checked exception because they indicate that something can go wrong. I don't except the compiler to parse every string I type. But still, "IllegalArgumentException" exists for a reason, and you will note that "[NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)"  derive from that type, so it's not uncommon for a java library class to provide a way to parse a type from a string without typed exception. Hence my question for such a parser for the URL class.

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy My theory is "the JDK 1.0 effect". The API design of that version isn't entirely consistent. Given the guidelines on when to use a checked exception and when an unchecked one, two developers came to different conclusions and nobody bothered to reconcile them.

Comment: @millimoose Indeed. MalformedURLException derive from... IOException? Now *that* is something weird. I don't think a mistyped url is a case of "failed or interrupted I/O operations."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since everyone else is just commenting, I will provide the answer which is that no there is no standard way to do what you want :)

Also, since you mention apache commons and google guava, I would point out that *standard* is not exactly the correct word to use either....maybe you want open-source, free, or just third-party.

Answer (score 11):

This complaint must have been a common one, because Java has (since 1.7) introduced the `URI` class. You can construct it using either of the following ways:

- `new URI()`, which throws a checked exception
- `URI.create()`, which throws an unchecked exception

For URIs/URLs like yours that are known to come from a safe source, you can use the `URI.create()` variant and not have to worry about catching the exception as you know it won't be thrown.

Unfortunately, sometimes you can't use a URI and you still need a URL. There's no standard method (that I have found so far) of converting a URI into a URL that doesn't throw a checked exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this one in the mix - there's a lot of stylistic variation for accomplishing the same thing, this one initializes in a static init block, but it can't be final.

```
public static URL g_url;

static {        

    try {
        g_url = new URL("http://www.example.org");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant extend URL because it is final, but you can create a new class, perhaps named MyURL, and have it proxy the URL methods to a private (or protected) URL member.

Here is the beginnings of such a class:

```
package blammo.url;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyURL
{
    private URL containedURL;

    public MyURL(final String spec)
    {
        try
        {
            containedURL = new URL(spec);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public String getAuthority()
    {
        return containedURL.getAuthority();
    }

    // required for stuff that needs a URL class.
    public URL getContainedURL()
    {
        return containedURL;
    }
}
```